# Python не хочет декодить в UTF-8

Tags: python, python-3.x, decode

Проблема такая:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Мой код жалуется только на те места, где в конце

```py
.decode("utf-8")
```

Сам код:

```py
process_name = "csgo.exe"
signatures = ""
mode = 1
scan_delay = 5

def crc(fileName):
    prev = 0
    for eachLine in open(fileName, "rb"):
        prev = zlib.crc32(eachLine, prev)
    return "%X"%(prev & 0xFFFFFFFF)

import os, subprocess, zlib, time
sigs_path = "./sigs/" + process_name + "_sigs.txt"
sigs_local_path = "./sig.txt"

if mode:
    sigs = subprocess.check_output('listdlls ' + process_name).decode("utf-8")
    f = open(sigs_path, 'w')
    f.write( sigs )
    f.close()
    
    f = open(sigs_local_path, 'w')
    f.write( sigs )
    f.close()
    
    while True:
        sigs = subprocess.check_output('listdlls ' + process_name).decode("utf-8")
        f.open(sigs_path, 'w')
        f.write( sigs )
        f.close()
        
        check = crc(sigs_path) == crc(sigs_local_path)
        
        if ( check ):
             time.sleep(scan_delay);
             continue;
        else:
             os.system('taskkill /im "' + process_name + '" /f')
             print( "Cheat is injected, closing game!" )
             break;
```

Comment: Ну, может, там действительно не utf-8?

Comment: @andreymal Я сам-то совсем не шарю в питоне, нашёл этот код в инете. Вполне возможно, что не utf-8.

Comment: @andreymal Я utf-16 тоже пробовал, но там вообще бешеная ошибка: return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 5531: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Ну так может cp866 или cp1251?

Comment: Есть модуль [`chardet`](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) для распознавания кодировки. Пример: `chardet.detect(open('file.txt', 'rb').read())` выдаст кодировку файла. Если питон более-менее новой версии (кажется, 3.5 или новее), можно использовать `universal_newlines` для декодировки: `subprocess.check_output(..., universal_newlines=True)`.

Comment: @hoefling Блин, помогло! Напиши ответ к моему вопросу, я его засчитаю как ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используй `universal_newlines` для автоматической декодировки:

```
subprocess.check_output(..., universal_newlines=True)
```

Начиная с Python 3.7, `universal_newlines` заменен на `text`:

```
subprocess.check_output(..., text=True)
```

Кроме того, если кодировка текста неизвестна, можно использовать модуль [`chardet`](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) для угадывания кодировки:

```
out = subprocess.check_output(...)
enc = chardet.detect(out).get('encoding', None)
if enc:
    decoded = out.decode(enc)
```